# Tampermonkey "function" not working properly

Tags: javascript, function, tampermonkey

I have written this piece of code and for some reason none of the code inside of the function actually runs, it just appears to skip over it. This is probably just me and my terrible knowledge of javascript but I cannot work it out for the life of me.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         PalaceBOTcheckout
// @namespace
// @version      0.1
// @description
// @author       @alfiefogg_
// @match        https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/*/checkouts/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step__footer__continue-btn btn ")[0].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName("step__footer__continue-btn btn ")[0].click();
    document.getElementById("number").value = ("");
    document.getElementById("name").value = ("");
    document.getElementById("expiry").value = ("");
    document.getElementById("verification_value").value = ("");
    document.getElementsByClassName("step__footer__continue-btn btn ")[0].click();
}, false);
```

I have also debugged the script in the chrome console window and it just skips all of the code in the function??

Comment: How have you determined this code is not being executed? If you place a `console.log('foo');` in there is it output in the console when the page runs?

Comment: Are you sure all of those class names and IDs are valid?

Comment: Have you tried it in any other browser?

Comment: The code inside will only be executed after the load event is triggered.

Comment: You can always add the line `debugger;` to your code where you want to break into the javascript debugger. This will let you see if your code is being executed or not. For this case, I'd consider using jquery or [the code listed here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready) instead of what you're using.

Comment: I have already debugged the code and to sum it up it runs the event listener and then completely skips everything in the function box and then skips to the bottom of the page to a line of code ("})}})(this.context, this.fapply, this.console)}).apply(window["__u__4722610.887817109_"])")

Comment: Also, all the code is completely functional it just doesn't run for some reason